How to adjust spindle nut that is not straight
Help please, a simple job to replace a broken window lock has got me baffled.  The nut or whatever it is that will hold the new spindle in the window frame is not straight and looks more to be a diamond shape than square.  How can I turn this to straighten it?

Click the "Edit" link to edit your post, then click the Mountain icon to add the picture.

do not use another account to add the picture ... use the same account as the question
